# Replace three points by text value

Tags: html, vba

I want to replace three points in the code source by text value. The text value will be declared in variable. May something help me? This the source code:

```html
<div class="msg-form__contenteditable t-14 t-black--light t-normal flex- 
grow-1" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="msg-form__contenteditable- 
placeholder-ember1146" contenteditable="true" aria-multiline="true"> 
<p>...</p></div>
```

This is my code, it doesn't work :

```vb
Set mess = ie.Document.all.Item("msg-form__contenteditable t-14 t-black-- 
light t-normal flex-grow-1")
mess.Value = "Hello world !"
```

Comment: What about your code doesn't work?

Comment: The [`Item` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms536460(v=vs.71)) of the [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms537434(v=vs.71)) `all` property finds elements by `name` and `id`. You are passing a collection of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without knowing which index that class is at/seeing more html

You can use css class selector e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("div.msg-form__contenteditable.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal.flex-.grow-1").item(0).value = "xyz"
```

Replace 0 with the appropriate index

You might also try something more unique e.g. with css attribute = value selector and ends with ($) operator:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-labelledby$='1146']").value = "xyz"
```

Similarly, with a longer selector substring:

```
[aria-labelledby$='placeholder-ember1146']
```

You can also combine the above:

```
ie.document.querySelector("div.msg-form__contenteditable.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal.flex-.grow-1[aria-labelledby$='placeholder-ember1146']").value = "xyz"
```